# Using pyodata, how do I list all available properties of a queried Entity?

Tags: python, odata

I want to dynamically list all available properties from an odata Entity using [PyOData package](https://pyodata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Here is what I'd like to do:

```py
service = pyodata.Client(SERVICE_URL, session)

positions = service.entity_sets.TRLPositionSet.get_entities().select('Prop1,Prop2').execute()
for p in positions:
 # how to implement get_properties below?
 properties = get_properties(p)
 for prop in properties:
   print(prop.name, getattr(p, prop.name)
```

How would I implement the `get_properties(p)` function to make it return a list `['Prop1', 'Prop2']`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:
https://github.com/SAP/python-pyodata/issues/53#issuecomment-533261246

for es in client.schema.entity_sets:
print(es.name)

```
proprties = es.entity_type.proprties()

for prop in es.entity_type.key_proprties:
    print(f' K {prop.name}({prop.typ.name})')
    proprties.remove(prop)

for prop in proprties:
    print(f' + {prop.name}({prop.typ.name})')

for prop in es.entity_type.nav_proprties:
    print(f' + {prop.name}({prop.to_role.entity_type_name})')
```

In my case I had to use `es._entity_type`